# Mac OS X, Node is installed by Nvm, but can't use module which is installed globally

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

The operation system is Mac OS X, After installing Node by using NVM, Node -v shows 9.2. And after installing express globally(npm install -g express), I cannot use express in the command line. If it is used, it will prompt that the module is not defined. Using npm root -g to find the installation of node path, in the lib or bin directory I can see the global installation of the package, but I can't be able to add lib or bin directory in the environment path, because there is no executable file in these two directories. 
Any suggestions are very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line program `express` is not installed with `npm install express`, no matter the command line parameters passed to it. To use the command line utility, you must globally install the package [`express-generator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator), like this:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

You also should probably install normal `express` to your individual project, and not globally

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, you are right, it's not nvm issue, i didn't install module correctly.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it! If this answer helped you, be sure to mark it as accepted to signal to others that your problem is resolved and that this answer worked for you